# Time.Sleep Alternative? Need to be able to break loop/return to main

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, pyautogui

```
import time
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *
import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
from PIL import *
import os
import win32api, win32con
import cv2
import pyperclip
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from threading import Event

##1340,182, 1777, 213
test = 0
src_path = os.getcwd()
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'


def get_region(box):
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im = im.save(os.getcwd() + "\\logs.png", 'PNG')

def get_string(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    red   = [0,0,255]
    img[img != red] = 255
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "\\logs.png", img)
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "\\logs.png"))
    return result

def alertf1(c):
    global test
    time.sleep(0.1)
    while c == 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):  # if key 'f1' is pressed 
            print('f1 has been pressed')
            c = 0
            break
        else:
            result = get_string(src_path + "\\logs.png")
            print('checking if anything is destroyed')
            if result.find('destroved') != -1:
                print('something got destroyed!')
                pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
                time.sleep(0.1)
                pyautogui.keyDown('tab')
                pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
                pyautogui.keyUp('tab')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                for char in '@':
                    pyperclip.copy(char)
                    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval=0.1)
                    pyautogui.write('everyone Enemies/Red Logs! Something has been destroyed.')
                    pyautogui.press('enter')
                    pyautogui.click(x=1860, y=50)
            else:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):  # if key 'f1' is pressed 
                    print('f1 has been pressed')
                    c = 0
                    break

def on_press(key):
    global test
    test = test + 1
    region = (1341,185, 1778, 215)
    get_region(region)
    if key == Key.f1 and test == 1:
        print('before alert f1 pressed')
        test = test + 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
        alertf1(1)
    if key == Key.f1 and test == 3:
        test = 0



with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

def main():
    while True:
        print('on press going now')
        on_press(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thats my current code, a small explanation of what it does and what I want:
Upon start, if user presses 'F1' it will take a screenshot of a small area and turn the image into text, it will then run an infinite loop, to check if the text I got from the image is = to 'destroyed' if it is then user gets notified and if it isn't it will be on a infinite loop getting new screenshots and checking it again.

I also added the "if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):" to  break the infinite loop.

The 2 issues I have right now:

1- After user gets notified I want the program to not proceed into the infinite loop for 5 minutes, time.sleep (300) works but the issue is that if the user wants to cancel the current function and presses F1 to break the loop back into Main() it will not get detected, thus I need another alternative to time.sleep because it just freezes the code completely. I heard that threading.event could work but I have honestly no idea how it works, and even after checking a couple examples I am not sure how I could make it work still.

2- I found that 'if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):' Isn't very effective as it sometimes doesn't trigger and have to click quite a few times until it triggers and breaks loop. What would be a good alternative?

Comment: Didn't we just talk about this?  Don't call `keyboard.is_pressed` anywhere except your `on_press` handler.  Let it set status flags that the other code can read.  Don't do a `time.sleep(300)`, do a `time.sleep(2)` or something in a loop, and then check the flag to see if the wait should be aborted.

Comment: @TimRoberts How can I add a status flags that allows the other function to read it even though it's been changed on my on_press function?

Comment: You don't have to change things.  `on_press` runs in a separate thread.  As soon as it sets the flag and exits, your other code will see the change.

Comment: shouldn't simply changing c=0 in on_press stop the loop? issue is that it doesn't.

Comment: The big problem with this design is that you are calling `alertf1` in your key handling loop.  As long as you are in `alertf1`., that thread is busy, and it can't fetch any more keystrokes.  You really need to launch `alertf1` as its own thread at startup.  `on_press` can set flags  to control the behavior of `alertf1`, but it can't launch it.

Comment: I see, so it all boils down to using another thread, I tried understanding how to use them before but seemed to complex couldn't get my head around it even after seeing a couple examples, guess I'll have to give it another try.

Comment: You're already using another thread, you just don't see it.  When you call "Listener", that actuall spins off a thread to do the keyboard processing.  It then returns control to you while the thread runs in the background.  When you call `listener.join()`, that says "block the main thread until the listener thread exits".  If you don't have ANY other processing, then you can just call `alertf1` instead of `listener.join()`.  Your main thread can watch for the signals while the keyboard happens in the background.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb about this but i still cant quite understand fully. So what you're saying I should be doing is remove listener.join() and instead, call alertf1 there, which I assume could have a if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'): before it to make sure it's called only when f1 has been pressed?

Then, I would get a global variable in the on_press and in the alertf1, and if I pressed F1 again, the global variable would change in the on_press thus changing also in alertf1 thus breaking the loop?

Comment: No, no, no; let the `on_press` handler handle the keys.  Let it tell you when the state changes.  `alertf1` will sit in a big loop and do nothing if the current state is "nothing to do" (just `sleep(0.5)` and `continue`).  When `on_press` sets a flag saying there is something to do, then you go do it.  Let `alertf1` be driven entire by state information updated by `on_press`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D4mYeNd6

Something like this?
Main just checks if global variable has been changed and if its value is '1' then it will run alert.

on_press function checks how many times F1 has been pressed to change the global variables to either start the alertf1 function or stop it or restart it if we press F1 again after stopping.

Issue is after pressing F1, startf1 global variable, IS getting assigned the value of 1 but the main() isn't running for some reason (even though its on a while True loop), I say it isnt running because I never get the print in main if startf1 == 1

Comment: You have the right thought, but remember that your app never gets to `main`.  You will block forever on the `listener.join()` waiting for the keypress thread to exit, which it won't ever do.

Comment: I found an issue though, apparently if alertf1() is running, regardless of what I press, on_press function never gets called again until alertf1() stops running. I tried adding prints to my on_press and they never show up if i try to get it work during ongoing loop

Comment: You will have to do `time.sleep(...)` to allow the other thread(s) to run.